# Finding difficulty to add one more sheet in Excel workbook using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

My following 3 line code is used to create one file with sheet1(Year 2019) now would like to execute another page and need to store the result of it in same file as sheet2(Year 2020).

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Year 2019");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\dp\\Desktop\\MData1_Test_1.xlsx");

Row header_1 = sheet.createRow(rowNum[0]);
        rowNum[0] = (rowNum[0] + 1);
        header_1.createCell(0).setCellValue("Analytics");
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? How it is failed? It would be as simple as `XSSFSheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("Year 2020");` ... `Row header_2 = sheet2.createRow(...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// open your first file
try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fut.get())) {
     Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

     // get sheet by name
     Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Year 2019");

     if (null != sheet) {
         // if sheet exists => delete it
         int index = wb.getSheetIndex(String name);
         wb.removeSheetAt(index);
     }

     // create new sheet
     sheet = wb.createSheet("Year 2019");

     // proceed adding data
     // row = sheet.createRow(0);
     // row.createCell(0).setCellValue("data");
     // ...
}
```

You can repeat these steps as many time as you need to manage as many sheets as you want.

Comment: I have 2 different pages for Year 2018 and for 2019. Both pages are running individually and writing data on different excel file. Now After writing on excel for 2018, would like to append one more sheet in same excel file (MData1_Test_1.xlsx.) and write the data for 2019.

Comment: Want to append one more sheet in my existing excel file. It will check first if already sheet is exist, will create one more sheet otherwise it will just create sheet.

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: Wanted to check whether sheet is exist then add new sheet otherwise write on sheet1.